# Codenameone LocalNotification in android api < 16 and when the app is removed from recent

Tags: android, codenameone

I am developing an app in codename one. I am trying to send user local notification from app. When the user opens the app I have schedule the `LocalNotification` as below.

```
@Override
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {
    Display.getInstance().cancelLocalNotification(notificationId);
    LocalNotification notification = new LocalNotification();
    notification.setId(notificationId);
    notification.setAlertTitle("Haven't seen you in long time");
    notification.setAlertBody("You have not visited us in long time. You are missing lots of good stuff");
    Date date = new Date();
    Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(notification, date.getTime()+threeMinute, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
    }
```

This is my `localNotificationReceived`.

```
@Override
public void localNotificationReceived(String notificationId) {
    Dialog.show("Welcome Back", "Have wonderful time ahead", "Ok", null);
    f.revalidate();
}
```

The problem are:

1. The notification gives error in android api level < 16. I think the problem is that the support library is not being used. How to use support library?
2. In api level 16 and above, the notification shows up but on clicking the notification, the dialog in `localNotificationReceived` is not shown.
3. When the app is removed from recent, app does not show any notification and crashes.

Can you provide any insight on this?

Comment: Did you define any build hints? Normally support should be included implicitly in the build

Comment: Nope I didnt know that. I will work on it now.
What about problem 2 and 3. The code in localNotificationReceived is not called. And if the app is removed from recent apps, the app crashes without any notification.

Comment: I don't really know enough about this, I've asked @chen-fishbein to take a look

Comment: Ok thanks. will wait on that.

Comment: I have added hint `android.supportV4` with value `true`. But it still showing the error.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.build

Answer (score 1):

it is likely the codenameone activity is not yet started and by trying to display a Dialog you are failing, try to just store to the storage and on the app start check the storage

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for Background and Foreground local notification.

```
if (isAppInForeground()) {
}
```

Notification

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon()).setTicker(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(regionList.getTitle() + geofenceId)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(regionList.getEntertext()))
                .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentText(regionList.getEntertext()).build();

       notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(geofenceId), notification);
```

check app is in background or foreground use below methods.

```
private boolean isAppInForeground() {

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> l = mActivityManager
            .getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> i = l.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = i.next();
        if (info.uid == getApplicationInfo().uid
                && info.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Background code

```
private boolean isAppInBackground() {

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> l = mActivityManager
            .getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> i = l.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = i.next();
       if (info.uid == getApplicationInfo().uid
                && info.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Cheers!!

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding but its in codenameone not from native android. I will mention it in question. Sorry for trouble.